# Bind jqGrid to JSON Object

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

How do I bind a simple JSON Object to a jqGrid?

Here's what I have:

```
    var tableSrc = { "page":"1", "total":1, "records":"3", "rows": [
        { "title": "Title1", "subtitle": "subTitle", "authors": ["a1", "a2", "a3"] },
        { "title": "Title2", "subtitle": "subtitle", "authors": ["X", "Y"] },
        { "title": "Title3", "subtitle": "subTitle", "authors": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]}]
    };

    $(".jqGridTarget").jqGrid({
        datastr: tableSrc,
        datatype: "jsonstring",
        colNames: ['title', 'subtitle'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'title', index: 'title', width: 55 },
            { name: 'subtitle', index: 'subtitle', width: 90}]
    });
```

And then:

```
<table class="jqGridTarget">
</table>
```

This yields the error:

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # inside of jQuery 1.6.2

I've also tried using json instead of jsonstring with data replacing datastr.  That eliminates the error, but the grid is still empty.  In both cases undefined appears, or flashes in the grid body.

**EDIT**

I've also tried datatype: "local" with tableSrc as data.  No error or undefined, but still no data in grid.

**END EDIT**

Also, here are the script/css files I have referenced:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.tmpl.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.jqGrid.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-1.2.1.js'></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui.jqgrid.css" />
```

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: I know, I know.  That's what most people call it though, so I figured I would just call it that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three changes are required to make your code working (see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AdamRackis.htm) the fixed demo):

1. add parameter jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }`
2. add and `id` to the `<table>` element
3. include `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` **before** `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`

Additionally I would recommend you to use always `gridview: true` and in the most cases define `height` as `height: 'auto'`.

Comment: It seems to work fine without step 3.  If I'm only working with an American audience, do I still need that?

Comment: @Adam Rackis: To work with jqGrid you do have to include `grid.locale-en.js`. Without this you will have another errors. The order of .js files are also very important. See [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `datatype: 'local'` and `data: tableSrc`.

> `datatype`: Defines what type of information to expect to represent data in the grid. Valid options are xml - we expect xml data; xmlstring - we expect xml data as string; json - we expect JSON data; jsonstring - we expect JSON data as string; local - we expect data defined at client side (array data); javascript - we expect javascript as data; function - custom defined function for retrieving data.
>
> `data`: A array that store the local data passed to the grid. You can directly point to this variable in case you want to load a array data. It can replace addRowData method which is slow on relative big data

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Comment: Sorry, I tried that too.  No error or "undefined" but still no data in grid.  I'll update my question.